# What is this symbol in KiCad schematics?

Tags: kicad

I'm making my first steps in electronics and am trying to redraw a schematic in KiCad to export it to Gerber files and make a PCB.

I found this symbol on a source schematic, but I cannot find it in KiCad.

I know it's a power source with +3.3 VDC, but a similar symbol also has a *spi_clock* connector. What is the common name for this graphical symbol?

What is the keyword or whatever to find it?

[image]

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's a **global label** which is used to name a signal.  It is connected to every other signal named the same, without drawing a wire; and because it's *global*, even on other sheets.  You choose the shape of the arrow to indicate input, output, bidirectional etc.  The purposes are to a) declutter the diagram, b) clearly label important signals.

Note that this is just a name you choose, there's nothing that makes a signal called `3V3 DC` actually be at 3.3 volts, unless you connect it to a suitable source.

[image]
*In this circuit, U1 pin 1 is connected to U2 pin 1*

Answer (score 3):

That's a global label - one that applies to all sheets in a project. If you only have one sheet then it is the same as a normal label and simply connects all things with that label together.